# Error on PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, queue

I'm trying to use an instance of the `PriorityBlockingQueue` class:

```
public static PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> messagesQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>();

public static void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
{
    messagesQueue.add(message);
}
```

and my compiler keeps throwing a weird error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
BlockingQueue cannot be resolved to a type  MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 46 Java Problem
BlockingQueue cannot be resolved to a type  MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 49 Java Problem
BlockingQueue cannot be resolved to a type  MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 64 Java Problem
BlockingQueue cannot be resolved to a type  MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 68 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token  IBaseNPC.java   /necrotek3d_v/src/GameInterfaces/NPCs   line 27 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", ; expected   MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 69 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "static", interface expected after this token MessageManager.java /necrotek3d_v/src/MessageManagement line 64 Java Problem
```

EDIT

Here is messagemanager:

```
public  class MessageManager extends Thread {
    @Override
    public  void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true)
        if (!messagesQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                //pull message from queue
                Message message = messagesQueue.remove();

                //dispatch messages according to their type
                switch(message.mflag)
                {
                case EM_BOOTSTRAP:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Messaging system working properly.");
                default:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Default Dispatch Message Trashed");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> messagesQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>();

    public static void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
    {
        messagesQueue.add(message);
    }

        //called upon when object is no longer needed

        public void Destroy()
        {
            //called Destroy
        }

        //called every turn. checks messagemanager for message

        public void ParseMessage()
        {

        }


        public static void Launch() {}


        //called on object creation

        public static void Init() {}



        public static void  Render()
        {

        }


        public static void  Collision()
        {

        }

        //when the game requires this particular state to be active

        public static void  OnEnter()
        {

        }

        //When the object no longer needs to be attachd to the scene graph

        public static void  OnExit()
        {
        }

        //for exammple, hitting the pause button

        public static void  OnSuspend()
        {
        }


    public static void Train()
    {
        //incoming messages are analyzed and sent
        //to the trainer to record the behavior for the AI
    }
```

}

And here is BaseNPC:

```
public interface IBaseNPC extends IBase {

    //AI TYPE

    int active_speed = 0;
    boolean allured = false;
    String corpse_name = new String();
    direct_damage = 0;
    energy_damage = 0;

    ///fight mode

    int [] home = new int[3];

    boolean is_bonded = false;
    boolean is_champion_spawned = false;
    boolean is_paragoned = false;
    boolean is_prisoner = false;
    boolean no_loot_on_death = false;
    int passive_speed = 0;
    int physical_damage = 0;
    int poison_damage = 0;
    boolean alive = true;
    int armor_rating = 0;

    int back_pack_index = 0;
    int bank_box_index = 0;
    boolean blessed = false;

    int body_type_index = 0;
    int body_value_index = 0;
    boolean can_hear_ghosts = false;
    boolean can_swim = false;
    boolean cant_walk = false;

    int cold_resistance = 0;
    //combatant
    //corpse
    boolean criminal = false;
    int dex = 0;
    int str = 0;
    int intel = 0;

    int emote_hue = 0;

    int face_hue = 0;
    int face_item_id = 0;

    int facial_hair_hue = 0;
    int facial_hair_item_id = 0;

    int flying = 0;

    int hair_hue = 0;
    int hair_item_id = 0;

    boolean hidden = false;
    int hue = 0;

    int hunger = 0;
    boolean is_stealthing;

    int kills = 0;

    int [] location = new int[3];

    int mana = 0;

    //map

    boolean meditating = false;

    //mount

    boolean mounted = false;
    boolean murderer = false;

    int name_hue = 0;

    boolean paralyzed = false;
    boolean poisoned = false;

    //race

    String raw_name = null;
    int speech_hue = 0;

    int thirst = 0;
    String title = null;

    int total_gold = 0;
    int total_items = 0;
    int total_weight = 0;

    int weapon = 0;
    boolean war_mode = false;

    //Chores:
    EChores chore = null;
    EMoods mood = null;
    ENPCActions npc_action = null;

    CAdvancedAISliders advanced_sliders = null;

    CAIBits ai_bits = null;

    CAnotherBitTable another_bits = null;

    CBaseStats  base_stats = null;

    CCharacterStatistics char_stats = null;

    CDynamicStats dynamic_stats = null;

    CEmotions emotions  = null;

    CInternalThingTable internal_thing = null;

    CKnowledgeAndLore knowledge_lore = null;

    CSkill skillls = null;

    CSocialBehaviorsSliders social_sliders = null;

    CThingInfoClass thing_info = null;

    CVvampireTable vampire_table = null;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the content of the files: `MessageManager.java` and `BaseNPC.java`?

Comment: MessageManager:

Answer (score 0):

All in all, the compiler has provided the list of the compilation errors, including the syntax errors, with their detailed descriptions. Just take a look at the every error carefully and correct the implementation appropriately.

Some of the issues that have been found.

## `IBaseNPC` interface

1. Some of the fields do not have the specified type. Consider updating the fields, for example, as follows:

   ```
   int direct_damage = 0;
   int energy_damage = 0;
   ```
2. The field lacks of the assigned value. Consider introducing the initialisation of the field, for example, as follows:

   ```
   boolean is_stealthing = false;
   ```

## `MessageManager` class

1. The curly brackets are not balanced. Consider correcting the curly brackets properly.

Comment: and, of course, you can't have non-static fields in an interface